# how to do sentiment scoring for any customer feedback

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

I have dataset which containing customer feedbacks for any products.I explored IBM watson, google sentiment analysis, they provide directly sentiment score. Also tried different algorithms:- Neavi Bayes, SVM, also by using LSTM model.

But here I need a pre label/score dataset for input to train the model. Can I one help me how can I do scoring for my dataset.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.

Answer (score 0):

https://dzone.com/articles/breakthrough-research-papers-and-models-for-sentim

have you looked at
Recursive Neural Tensor Network

RNTN was introduced in 2011-2012 by Richard Socher et al. from Standford’s NLP group. The authors introduced the Recursive Neural Tensor Network, which was trained on a different kind of dataset called the Standford Sentiment Treebank. The Stanford Sentiment Treebank was the first dataset with fully labeled parse trees that allows for a complete analysis of the compositional effects of sentiment, analyzing the intricacies of sentiment, and capturing complex linguistic phenomena.